# How to calculate how lighter a ceiling fan is while switched on vs switched off?

Tags: gravity, aerodynamics

For as a pushed air downwards it should feel a force upwards because of that.
Can we calculate how lighter it becomes w.r.t. speed.

Comment: I suggest that you look up "helicopter lift" or something similar.

Comment: With the information you have provided, the thrust due to the fan cannot be calculated. You need to provide the structure of the fan. However, you can report the thrust provided by the fan using volume of air pushed.

Comment: http://blog.ceilingfan.com/5-factors-that-determine-ceiling-fan-airflow/   when you bought the fan, I would guess it gave you some idea of how much airflow it created. You should be able to get some ideas from that.